# RWD: Adding to the product page

Tags: extensions, products, rwd, rwd-theme

My difficulties with RWD continue.

The recurring theme is: An extension works fine on any theme but RWD.

The extension Product Inquiry (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-inquiry-1.html) creates a form on the bottom of the product page.

It works fine on a clean install of CE 1.9 on any theme that is not RWD.

But it does not appear on the front end for RWD. I checked the template path hints, and the page doesn't call this extension.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support. Contact the developer for this.

Comment: Sorry if it appears off-topic. It is just that there are several extensions that work on every other theme, but do not appear in RWD. I am trying to understand how the RWD theme works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the module has any files in app/design/default/default and skin/frontend/default/default. If so, move those files into app/design/rwd/default and skin/frontend/rwd/default, respectively.

If you send a listing of all of the files in the module (`find .`), that would also help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem! I really appreciate your help!